# django-paypal PDT implementation can't receive signals

Tags: django, django-paypal

I am trying to implement django-paypal (dcramers version from git) using PDT with subscriptions.

It works fine (meaning that the `return_url` is requested and answered), however signals are not triggered (put in models.py). I am using the following signals, connected to two different functions.

`from paypal.standard.pdt.signals import pdt_successful, pdt_failed`

What I noticed while browsing through my access logs is that I do get a POST request from paypal which is turned down.

`"POST /an-obscure-string/pdt/ HTTP/1.0" 401 401 "-" "-"`

I tried to modify `/paypal/standard/pdt/views.py` to accept POST requests but I still get the 401 error. I think this is the reason signals are not triggered.

I am having a bad time with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I am using the sandbox account

EDIT These are my PAYPAL POSTBACK values from `conf.py`

```
POSTBACK_ENDPOINT = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
SANDBOX_POSTBACK_ENDPOINT = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
```

Answer (score 2):

You are right, that is the reason why the signal does not get called since signals are sent at the very end of the view if the model's verify succeed.

Your solution is indeed wrong, Paypal will definitely send a GET request with the transaction ID to your app url if you choosed to use PDN.

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_html_paymentdatatransfer

I really suggest you to check your settings (on paypal account) since you are probably using IPN which uses POST requests.

Another possible cause of this is that after you received the GET request from paypal your app sends the POST data to your app instead of to paypal postback endpoint. (https://github.com/johnboxall/django-paypal/blob/master/standard/pdt/models.py#L47)

I would look at the access logs to see if the POST request comes after a GET request (for the same url), if yes I would check the value of the SANDBOX_POSTBACK_ENDPOINT and POSTBACK_ENDPOINT settings.

Comment: Thank you very much. What do you mean by PDN? And yes in the past I have tried to set up IPN. Should I just avoid PDT solution and try to use only IPN? What is your opinion? I get the feeling that many devs prefer PDT over IPN for some reason. I will check my paypal settings and report here.

Comment: I checked my paypal settings and IPN is turned off.

Comment: Also I noticed that on the PDT section (where I have selected to use PDT and got my PDT Token) there it says: "PayPal will post a token associated with the transaction,"

Comment: Thank you again. I am not at my working pc at the moment, but I don't have to check the access logs. I remember well that yes POST request comes after the GET request. This is also something that puzzled me. I will check my settings as soon as I can and report back.

Comment: I turned to ipn. I still get a 401. So either my problem lies in paypal settings or my apache settings. Any idea, anyone?

Comment: @xpanta did you turned both app and paypal settings? do you have http authentication? do you still get the 401 for the POST method ? well, hope by answering this questions you can get to the problem :)